# multiple forms with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show forms according to user input in the text box but it is showing it one time only...please help...

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="demo1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="su">
<input type="text" name="tt" onkeyup="javascript:toggleFormVisibility();" id="sub"/>     </a>
</form>

<form id="subscribe_frm" style="display:none">
NAME:<input type="text" name="text">
EMAIL:<input type="text" name="text">
PASSWORD:<input type="text" name="text">
</form>
```

demo.js:

```
function toggleFormVisibility()
{


 var txt = document.getElementById('sub').value;

 for(var i=0;i<txt;i++)
{
 var frm_element = document.getElementById('subscribe_frm'); 
 var vis = frm_element.style;
 vis.display = 'block';

}      

}
```

Comment: Tip: onkeyup="javascript:toggleFormVisibility();" -- "javascript" is implied. No need to add it here.

Comment: You say it is showing one time only. What do you want it to be doing, then?

Comment: suppose i type 3 in text box so i want it to display the form 3 times ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a guess, but I think you are trying to create multiple copies of your form.  Try this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/QnrM9/

### JS

```
function toggleFormVisibility() {

    var txt = document.getElementById('sub').value;
    var neededChildren = txt.length - document.getElementById('form_container').children.length + 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < neededChildren; i++) {
        var frm_element = document.getElementById('subscribe_frm').cloneNode(true);
        var vis = frm_element.style;
        vis['display'] = 'block';
        document.getElementById("form_container").appendChild(frm_element);
    }

}
document.getElementById('sub').addEventListener('keyup', toggleFormVisibility);
```

### HTML

```
<form name="su">
    <input type="text" name="tt" id="sub" />
</form>
<div id="form_container">
    <form id="subscribe_frm" style="display:none">NAME:
        <input type="text" name="text" />EMAIL:
        <input type="text" name="text" />PASSWORD:
        <input type="text" name="text" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is doing the same thing as my code but i want different thing.suppose i write 2 in text box so code should display form 2 times this is what i want ..

Comment: vatsal, there is a check mark next to my answer on the left hand side, you just need to click that to accept it.  thanks.